# Import connection manager SSIS to execute utility

Tags: sql, ssis, integration

I have a project that has some connection managers configured. I deployed a package to the integration services server.

When I run this package on Visual Studio it runs fine. But when I try to execute this on the server it fails.

I get the following error msg:
"The runtime connection manager with the ID "aaa" cannot be found. 
Verify that the connection manager collection has a connection manager with that ID.

How can I configure my connections on the server?

Thx

Comment: Do you have connection information passed as a parameter, or connection string configured to XML or Environment variables? Please check that the server is using the same connection string what you have in Visual Studio.

Comment: How can I make the server use the same connections that I have configure on the connection managers on VS?

Comment: Are you using xml configurations?

Comment: No. I didn't do anything with my connections yet

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140237.aspx

I believe this page contains the answer you are looking for. The SSIS designer has a "Connection Managers" area where you can edit the connection information.

> In SSIS Designer, click the Control Flow tab, the Data Flow tab, or
>   the Event Handler tab to make the Connection Managers area available.

Comment: I've already created my connections on Visual Studio. Now I want to know how to use this connections on the execution utilities on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, connections need to be at the package level, not the project level.  There is an option to right-click on the connection and covert them to package level.